# Как правильно сгенерировать колонки?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datatable

Работаю на WPF. Суть такая:
Загружаю из mysql БД в DataTable таблицу, так:

```
public void GetTableData(string curTable)
    {
        cmd = new MySqlCommand($"SELECT * FROM {curTable};", conn);
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        dt.Load(reader);
    }
```

Привязываю к DataGrid:

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = App.connection; // класс viewmodel
        DataGrid_main.ItemsSource = App.connection.DataTableView.DefaultView;
    }
```

Еще пробовал так

```
public DataTable DataTableView
    {
        get
        {
            return dt;
        }
        set
        {
            dt = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("DataTableView");
        }
    }
```

```xaml
<DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid_main" Margin="0,25,0,0" AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding DataTableView}"/>
```

В DataTable данные загружаются, есть вся информация о таблицу, начиная от количества строк и столбцов, заканчивая их значениями и названиями.
Визуализатор DataTable вот что показывает (собственно то как мне и надо что б показывалось в DataGrid)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но пытаясь вывести это в таблицу DataGrid с автогенерацией столбцов, получаю то что ниже на скрине. Причем как я понял столбцов самих нет, но количество строк точно в районе 3600 которые собственно находятся в базе.
Испробовал датасет с датаАдаптером, эффект тот же. Уже не знаю куда копать...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Загружать надо в свойство, а не в поле. Вообще вне сеттера свойства лушче не обращаться к полю этого свойства.

```csharp
public void GetTableData(string curTable)
{
    cmd = new MySqlCommand($"SELECT * FROM {curTable};", conn);
    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Load(reader);
    DataTableView = table;
}
```

2) В целях упрощения рефакторинга рекомендую использовать `nameof` в свойствах, иначе при переименовании свойства вы можете поломать приложение, забыв поменять строчку.

```csharp
public DataTable DataTableView
{
    get => dt;
    set
    {
        dt = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(DataTableView));
    }
}
```

3) Уберите лишнее присвоение `ItemsSource`, у вас есть `Binding`, пусть он это все обслуживает. (скорее всего здесь и кроется ваша исходная проблема)

```csharp
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = App.connection;
}
```

4) И если у вас где-то есть такое

```csharp
dt = new DataTable();
```

Замените его на

```csharp
DataTableView = new DataTable();
```

Иначе не будет толку от `OnPropertyChanged()`

Кстати, `AutoGenerateColumns="True"` - это дефолтное значение для `DataGrid`, то есть можно убрать, и ничего не поменяется.

Comment: Спасибо за правки, внесу их. А для чего тогда нужен автогенерейт? Я думал как раз что бы столбики создались сами как в DataTable

Comment: @МаксимРосолов Да, для столбиков, все верно. Но я написал про другое: что `DataGrid` имеет значение для `AutoGenerateColumns` по умолчанию `true`. И явно указывать это в XAML нет необходимости.

Comment: Понял. Правки внес, и я так понял они для Правильного кода, по скольку основную проблему не решили.

Comment: @МаксимРосолов нет, у вас было присвоение `ItemsSource` в конструкторе, вы его убрали?

Comment: я сделал в xaml биндинг к свойству `DataTableView` , а в конструкторе его убрал. Как я лично понимаю, `DataGrid` видит `DataTable`, но не понимает как создать колонки ибо количество строк совпадает с тем что в базе, и по этой же причине он не может заполнить данными ибо нет колонок к которым обращаться. Какие могут быть причины того, что он не знает как создать колонки?

Comment: @МаксимРосолов я доработал метод `GetTableData` в ответе, попробуйте.

Comment: Работает оО Жесть, спасибо!! но как? Почему? Чего бы я точно никогда бы не попробовал, так это ЭТО. Как узнали что это поможет? Я понимаю что вероятно опыт, но все же, как к таким решениям приходят?

Comment: @МаксимРосолов это просто, на момент запуска метода, `DataTable` уже привязана к `DataGrid`, а `DataGrid` генерит колонки только тогда, когда меняется `ItemsSource`, но не умеет это делать когда уже все присвоено. Да и `DataTable` вроде не имеет механизма уведомления для `Binding`. Поэтому, сначала загружаем полностью, а потом присваиваем. А вот уведомление об изменении состава строк в `DataTable` есть, и `DataGrid` его поддерживает динамически. Другими словами, чтобы поменять строки, вам ничего не надо делать, а для изменения колонок - только переприсваивать свойство.