# Почему datagrid заполняется не всегда?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, datatable

Вот уже пару дней пытаюсь привести программу в чистый MVVM.
Весь код привел в порядок быстро, но вот заполнить DataGrid (wpf) получается как-то криво. Для начала код:
Модель

```
public class MyModel : BindableBase
{
    DataGrid dg = new DataGrid();
    public DataTable DataTableView
    {
        get
        {
            return dt;
        }
        set
        {
            dt = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(DataTableView));
        }
    }
}
```

Модель представления

```
public class MyViewModel : BindableBase
{
     MyModel myModel = new MyModel();
     public MyViewModel()
    {
        myModel = App.myModel; \\ ссылка на модель, что б не юзать приставку App
        myModel.PropertyChanged += (s, e) => { RaisePropertyChanged(e.PropertyName); };
    }
 }
 public DataTable DT { get { return myModel.DataTableView;  } set {  myModel.DataTableView = value; RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(DT)); } }
```

В mainwindow

```
DataContext = App.myViewModel;
```

В XAML

```html
<DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid_main" Margin="0,25,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding DT, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" AlternatingRowBackground="#FFE8E8E8" FontSize="14"/>
```

Так вот, таблица DataGrid не заполняется, хотя если дописать в свойстве в модели представления messagebox, то заполняется

```
public DataTable DT { get { MessageBox.Show(myModel.DataTableView.Rows.Count.ToString()); return myModel.DataTableView;  } set {  myModel.DataTableView = value; RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(DT)); } }
```

Я не понимаю, как это вообще влияет то... К слову в модели представления есть еще куча свойств и DelegateCommand (которые так же обращаются к myModel), все работают как положено

Comment: А почему static то? Если у вас все приложение построено на static, то это плохо!

Comment: нет, просто забыл удалить, в модели представления.

Comment: Без static пробовали?

Comment: только что убрал и статик и паблик, результат тот же

Comment: Почему мне кажется, что источник проблемы тот же, что и в [прошлый раз](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1138793/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%b3%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%b8) в вашем вопросе? Все указывает на `DataTableView.Load(...)` и отсутствие генерации колонок, потому что `DataGrid` не получает `PropertyChanged` по факту загрузки данных.

Comment: похоже что так и есть. Ваше решение в прошлой теме, перенес в модель представления, проблема исчезла(проверил кнопкой Обновить, которая перезагружала датагрид уже после запуска программы), но появились проблемы с 'async', которыми видимо я увлекся сильно... Пойду редактировать код, если все получится, напишу решение.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в не правильном присвоении данных из datatable.
**Раньше**: в Модели метод заполнял свойство `DataTable`, а свойство Модели Представления обращалась к свойству Модели,
**Теперь**: В Модели больше нет свойства `DataTable`, теперь Модель методом возвращает заполненную `DataTable` в Метод в Модели Представления, где оно присваивается свойству

```
public async void GetTableData()
    {
        DataTable dt_temp = new DataTable();
        await Task.Run(() => dt_temp = myModel.GetTableData2()); // GetTableData2() - метод в модели, что возвращает заполненную DataTable
        DT = dt_temp; // DT - свойство DataTable
    }
```

Comment: `public async void GetTableDataAsync()` дописывайте `Async` в конец названия метода, если он асинхронный ([рекомендация Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/async#important-info-and-advice)). Потом, `async void` - это проблемная штуковина ([первая попавшаяся ссылка в тему](https://andrey.moveax.ru/post/csharp-do-not-user-async-void))

Comment: По поводу рекомендации понял, а вот про async не совсем. У меня вроде как таких проблем не было как указано в статье, следующий код выполнялся только после завершения await. возможно это потому, что вызов я делал так await Task.Run(() => метод ());

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется если у вас после MessageBox это всё работает, то проблема не хватает задержки и поток не успевает прорисовать greed. Попробуйте расинхронизировать или синхронизировать потоки поставьте async await.