Получение значения Text свойства TextBox, вложенного в элемент управления DataGrid
Я разрабатываю приложение, одной из функций которого является открытие файла базы данных и записи информации в поля одной из её таблиц. Собственно, разметка таблицы у меня получается абсолютно правильная:
DataGrid (XAML):
<DataGrid x:Name="gridTables"  Margin="0,49,0,0"/>

Стиль ячеек DataGrid(XAML):
<Window.Resources>
   <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
      <Setter Property="Template">
          <Setter.Value>
              <ControlTemplate>
                  <TextBox Name="textElement"/>
              </ControlTemplate>
          </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
   </Style>
</Window.Resources>

Разметка таблицы (C#):
string currentTable = "Название таблицы базы данных";
//TableViewModel - собственный класс, внутри которого происходит подключение к базе данных
viewModelTable = new TableViewModel("Строка подключения к базе данных", currentTable);

gridTables.Columns.Clear();
gridTables.Items.Clear();
foreach (var item in viewModelTable.Dates)
{
    DataGridTextColumn colName = new DataGridTextColumn();
    colName.Header = item.NameText;
    gridTables.Columns.Add(colName);
}



Но после заполнения ячеек таблицы и например нажатия на условную кнопку "Сохранить" мне бы хотелось извлечь данные из вложенных TextBox-ов в какой-либо массив/лист для дальнейшей работы с ними. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как этого можно достичь?

Почитайте про Data Binding, если коротко - вам не нужно получать содержимое TextBox-ов, а нужно создать, например, Observable Collection, настроить привязку ячеек таблицы к ее содержимому - и WPF всё сделает за вас, вы будете работать только с элементами этой коллекции, не обращаясь к слою View

Я вам под предыдущим вопросом написал подробно куда вам надо двигаться и как, даже пример показал, вы меня естественно проигнорировали и сейчас делаете опять непонятную, бесполезную ерунду, игнорируя то, как пишут в WPF... Зачем тогда задавать вопрос, если вы не слушаете то, чего вам говорят? Повторю, вам выше вон правильно сказали - делайте привязки. вы не должны хотеть обращаться к UI элементам через C# код!, забудьте просто про это. UI не для хранения данных, а именно это вы сейчас и делаете. Еще раз перечитайте мой комментарий под предыдущим вопросом и поймите что там написано.

Присоединяюсь к пожеланиям использовать привязки данных. Это в разы проще, чем сделать то, о чём вы просите. Но если очень хочется, то познакомьтесь с VisualTreeHelper, помучайтесь с ним, а потом всё равно используйте привязки.

Показанный стиль ячейки ломает DataGrid, так как опять же текстбокс надо привязывать через двухстороннюю привязку, либо использовать ContentPresenter. Вообще непонятно, зачем вам этот стиль. Стиль ячейки состоит из двух частей: стиль при отображении и стиль при редактировании. Вы переопределили стиль отображения, сломали таблицу, и пытаетесь на сломанном ехать. Начните с того, чтобы убрать этот стиль.

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1138906/373567 вот один из вариантов решения. Вот ещё один пример https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1251717/373567
